# Can we break RSA/AES encrypted document using quantum algorithms? If yes, How can we do it?

Tags: cryptography, aes, rsa, quantum-computing

RSA and AES-256 are defined standards for encrypting "Top Secret" documents. Is it possible to attack using quantum algorithms like shor's and grover's?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow... please have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768807/quantum-computing-and-encryption-breaking

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cryptography, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

The best quantum algorithm known for breaking symmetric ciphers is Grover's algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm
With Grover's algorithm we can break AES-256 with complexity 2^128. This is impossible with current quantum computers and any quantum computer we're likely to see within our lifetimes. In short, AES-256 is not breakable using current quantum algorithms.

The same is not true of RSA. RSA is breakable with quantum algorithms, but not with current quantum computers. So for now, you are safe using RSA (or DSA or ECDSA), but if quantum computers get a lot better (**if**, not **when**), we may need to switch to different signature methods. There is quite a bit of research about this called post-quantum cryptography.